# metaprogramming for params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

How can I update these very similar text fields in a less verbose way? The text fields below are named as given - I haven't edited them for this question.

```
  def update
    company = Company.find(current_user.client_id)
    company.text11 = params[:content][:text11][:value]
    company.text12 = params[:content][:text12][:value]
    company.text13 = params[:content][:text13][:value]
# etc
    company.save!
    render text: ""
  end
```

I've tried using `send` and `to_sym` but no luck so far...

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You probably shouldn't have 13 ambiguously named text columns on your companies table. You could either serialize this data into a single text column, or, and this is the better choice in most cases, make a TextContent model so your company `has_many :text_contents`.

Comment: Yeah. That's the problem with working on the same app for two years... crappy code remains from when I knew even less than I do now...

Comment: That's the beauty of refactoring most OO applications…you can improve what's there without rewriting the whole damn thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[:text11, :text12, :text13].each do |s|
    company.send("#{s}=".to_sym, params[:content][s][:value])
end
```

If they are all incremental numbers, then:

```
11.upto(13).map{|n| "text#{n}".to_sym}.each do |s|
    company.send("#{s}=".to_sym, params[:content][s][:value])
end
```

Comment: Ta, looks good - though I'm getting `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0))` on the second line of the first option you've given here...

Comment: Thanks for this... now getting `NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)` on the same line...

Comment: with params `  Parameters: {"content"=>{"text11"=>{"type"=>"full", "value"=>"<h5>We are super.&nbsp;</h5>"}, "text12"=>{"type"=>"full", "value"=>"<h1>\n        </h1><h1>\n                </h1><h3>Trophy shelf!</h3><h5></h5>"}}}
`

Comment: There, fixed it again. Sorry.

Comment: oh, and I've changed the array to [:text11=, :text12=].each etc

Comment: send expects the name of the method, which is "text{number}=" (note the '=').

Comment: Genius - thanks so much. I never get such good service when I pay for it!

Comment: Well you can pay me if you want :) j/k

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider first cleaning up the params, then move onto dynamically assigning attributes. A wrapper class around your params would allow you to more easily unit test this code. Maybe this helps get you started.

```
require 'ostruct'

class CompanyParamsWrapper

  attr_accessor :text11, :text12, :text13

  def initialize(params)
    @content = params[:content]
    content_struct = OpenStruct.new(@content)
    self.text11 = content_struct.text11[:value]
    self.text12 = content_struct.text12[:value]
    self.text13 = content_struct.text13[:value]
  end
end

# Company model
wrapper = CompanyParamsWrapper.new(params)
company.text11 = wrapper.text11

# now easier to use Object#send or other dynamic looping
```